# Changing background color in C++

Tags: c++, windows, turbo-c++

How to change background color of output screen without getting into graphics mode in turbo C++. I am using turbo C++ in windows xp . Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Kinda vague. Is this a console app? Is it Windows?

Comment: Turbo C++ was last updated eight years ago... maybe it's time to get a modern IDE & compiler? Take a look at NetBeans or Eclipse instead.

Comment: "without getting into graphics mode" -> console app. If you asked me 20 years ago, I might have been able to help.

Comment: **Step 1:** Press _Alt+Enter_ to restore the output window. **Step 2:** _Right Click_ over the icon on the title bar and select _Properties_ from the menu. **Step 3:** Select _colors_ tab to change the _background_ and _text_ color

Answer (score 2):

Here's some old code I haven't used in a while. You're welcome to it...

```
enum {White, Blue, Green, Red, Yellow, Cyan, Magenta, Black,
      Grey, DarkBlue, DarkGreen, DarkRed, DarkYellow, DarkCyan, DarkMagenta};

void ISC_Console::SetColor(int nForeground, int nBackground)
{
    ::SetConsoleTextAttribute(::GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),
        MakeFColor(nForeground) | MakeBColor(nBackground));
}

int ISC_Console::MakeFColor(int nColor)
{
    int nVal = 0;
    switch (nColor) {
    case Grey:
    case White:
        nVal = FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_BLUE;
        break;
    case Red:
    case DarkRed:
        nVal = FOREGROUND_RED;
        break;
    case Green:
    case DarkGreen:
        nVal = FOREGROUND_GREEN;
        break;
    case Blue:
    case DarkBlue:
        nVal = FOREGROUND_BLUE;
        break;
    case Yellow:
    case DarkYellow:
        nVal = FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN;
        break;
    case Cyan:
    case DarkCyan:
        nVal = FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_BLUE;
        break;
    case Magenta:
    case DarkMagenta:
        nVal = FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_BLUE;
        break;
    }
    if (nColor < Black) nVal |= FOREGROUND_INTENSITY;
    return nVal;
}

int ISC_Console::MakeBColor(int nColor)
{
        int nVal = 0;
    switch (nColor) {
    case Grey:
    case White:
        nVal = BACKGROUND_RED | BACKGROUND_GREEN | BACKGROUND_BLUE;
        break;
    case Red:
    case DarkRed:
        nVal = BACKGROUND_RED;
        break;
    case Green:
    case DarkGreen:
        nVal = BACKGROUND_GREEN;
        break;
    case Blue:
    case DarkBlue:
        nVal = BACKGROUND_BLUE;
        break;
    case Yellow:
    case DarkYellow:
        nVal = BACKGROUND_RED | BACKGROUND_GREEN;
        break;
    case Cyan:
    case DarkCyan:
        nVal = BACKGROUND_GREEN | BACKGROUND_BLUE;
        break;
    case Magenta:
    case DarkMagenta:
        nVal = BACKGROUND_RED | BACKGROUND_BLUE;
        break;
    }
    if (nColor < Black) nVal |= BACKGROUND_INTENSITY;
    return nVal;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't remember how much access to windows api calls Turbo C++ has.

Comment: If nothing else, this is woefully incomplete and won't build on its own.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you wanis to change the background of the output screen while outputting text.
You just have to include conio.h header file and use the built in function textbackground(COLOR) .

Answer (score 0):

This one is from TC help ...

```
#include <conio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i, j;

    clrscr();
    for (i=0; i<9; i++)
    {
       for (j=0; j<80; j++)
          cprintf("C");
       cprintf("\r\n");
       textcolor(i+1);
       textbackground(i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`textbackground()` can change the background of textmode console.